# AWS Federated User - multiple aws accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml-2.0

I'm not sure wether or not this is possible. We have a couple of different Amazon Web Service Accounts, in this case let us just call them:
Test environment 1
Test environment 2
Production environment

I really want to manage as much as possible with our google accounts. Let us say, as a developer i have access to all three accounts in AWS, and i want to be able to access all these accounts with this one mail. (is this even possible?).

I have tried following this guide: https://wheniwork.engineering/how-to-setup-google-sso-and-aws-4496f054a707

The saml login with google works just fine, but im not really sure how i can change accounts while logged in? 
[image]

I would love for it to show all organizations that i have access to, and change between them

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is already provided by the AWS and it's called '[AWS Landing Zone](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/aws-landing-zone/)'

Using Landing Zone, you can spin up multiple AWS accounts, and log in using one credential (Ex: your existing AD credentials)

**SSO**

[image]

**Accounts**
[image]

If you are new to this, I suggest looking at this [AWS Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvbiXJZmu4I) to get an idea about it.